# Cloudformation cannot set resource for IAM role

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-iam

I want to create an S3 bucket and a role that allows another service to access it using Cloudformation in YAML.

```
Resources:
S3SFTPBucket:
    Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
    DeletionPolicy: Retain
    Properties:
      BucketName: !Sub ${Env}-sftp-${AWS::AccountId}
      PublicAccessBlockConfiguration: 
        BlockPublicAcls: true
        BlockPublicPolicy: true
        IgnorePublicAcls: true
        RestrictPublicBuckets: true
  SFTPIAMRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      RoleName: !Sub ${Env}-sftp-${AWS::AccountId}-role
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: "2012-10-17"
        Statement:
          - Effect: "Allow"
            Principal:
              Service:
                - "transfer.amazonaws.com"
            Action:
              - "sts:AssumeRole"
            Resource:
            - !GetAtt S3SFTPBucket.Arn
      ManagedPolicyArns:
        - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonS3FullAccess
```

The bit I'm struggling with is

```
Resource:
  - !GetAtt S3SFTPBucket.Arn
```

In the role. When I set it to `"*"` it works fine.
When I set it to `!GetAtt S3SFTPBucket.Arn` or even `!Sub  arn:aws:s3:::${Env}-sftp-${AWS::AccountId}` I am getting an error in Cloudformation:

```
Has prohibited field Resource (Service: AmazonIdentityManagement; Status Code: 400; Error Code: MalformedPolicyDocument; Request ID: 564fe8df-b168-486b-a11e-5ef7b5689a13; Proxy: null)
```

I am also using the cfn policy validator and when I check the files with the 'incorrect' values I am getting the following response:

```
ERROR: Failed to create access preview for dev-sftp-078904673178-role.  Validate that your trust or resource policy's schema is correct.
```

How can I set the Resource in IAM role policy document to a dynamic value and make it work?

Answer (score 1):

`AssumeRolePolicyDocument` is a [resource-based policies](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_policies.html#policies_resource-based) and does do **not have** `Resource` argument. So you can't create `AssumeRolePolicyDocument` with `Resource`.

Instead you can use [S3 bucket policies](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/example-bucket-policies.html) to control access of IAM roles to your bucket.

Comment: What is this about then? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-iam-role.html#aws-resource-iam-role--examples

Comment: @davidb What about this? In your link `AssumeRolePolicyDocument` does not have `Resource`.

Comment: I will need to google about this a bit more. The role I'm trying to create here is actually going to be assigned to an sftp user. I will try to work on this. Thanks for the suggestion.